# The classification of developable surfaces: Are these statements equivalent?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

This is a cross-post from MSE (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4330772/242708).

I thought to know very well the answer to the classification problem for developable surfaces, so I sought for some confirmation in the literature. However, what I encountered are seemingly inequivalent statements that I am not sure how to interpret.

Recall that a smooth surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is said to be *developable* if it is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (or, equivalently, if its Gaussian curvature vanishes).

First off, what I thought was true is the following statement, present for example in Pressley's *Elementary differential geometry*, 2nd edition, at page 203:

> If $S$ is developable, then it is the union of (generalized) cylinders, (generalized) cones, and tangent developables, joined together along segments of straight lines.

However, if one checks Do Carmo's *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* (2nd edition, pp. 197–198), then one gets a seemingly different answer. After listing cylinders, cones, and tangent surfaces, he writes:

> "Of course, the above cases do not exhaust all possibilities. As usual, if there is a clustering of zeros of the functions involved, the analysis may become rather complicated. At any rate, away from these cluster points, a developable surface is a union of pieces of cylinders, cones, and tangent surfaces."

So he affirms that Pressley's claim is only valid ***away from cluster points***. The same conclusion is also drawn in Gray's *Modern differential geometry of curves and surfaces with Mathematica* (3rd edition, p. 448).

As if that weren't enough, another seemingly different statement is given in Kühnel's *Differential geometry. Curves—surfaces—manifolds* (3rd edition, p. 88):

> "An open and dense subset of every torse [= developable surface] consists of pieces of planes, cones, cylinders or tangent developable".

So my questions are the following. Are all these statements really equivalent? If so, why?

Comment: The statement of  Pressley is not quite correct, but it is not stated as a theorem and in principle "joined together along segments of straight lines" can be interpreted as you wish --- maybe there is a continuum of line segments...

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Thanks a lot for your comment! What still puzzles me is Kühnel's statement. Why do we need to restrict the classification to an *open and dense* subset?

Comment: To not consider cluster points.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Sure, but I do not understand why we have to exclude them. I wonder how a developable looks like at cluster points.

Comment: Let K be the Cantor set and $I_n$ be the open intervals in its complement. Imagine a surface parametrized by $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that it has a random cone structure on each $I_n\times[0,1]$. Then $K\times[0,1]$ is the set of cluster points.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin But the set $K \times [0,1]$ has measure zero in $[0,1]^{2}$, right? Maybe I am missing something trivial, but in your example any two pair of cones are joined along $\{p\}\times [0,1]$ for some $p \in K$. So I agree that Pressley's statement is not correct, but I still fail to see why Kühnel's would not be valid without the phrase "an open and dense subset of".

Comment: Cantor set might have positive measure.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I see, but still a Cantor set does not contain any open interval. So, once we have a cone in each open interval, the developable in question must be a union of (closed) cones. Do you agree?

Comment: No, I do not agree. Cantor set is not the union of the ends of intervals of its complement.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Yes, you are (of course) right. Thanks for the helpful discussion!